# MySQL UPDATE using IF to select which column to +1

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-update

I have a vote table, and if the POST value is 1 then update tableA column_a +1
else update tableA column_b +1

And here is my query, no idea how to use IF statement here.

```
UPDATE 
    votes, 
    topics 
SET votes.yesno = 1,
    IF(votes.yesno = 1, topics.num_yes = topics.num_yes+1, topics.num_no = topics.num_no+1)
WHERE votes.user_id=? AND votes.topic_id=?
AND topics.id = votes.topic_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for.  You can't use IF to specify a column, but you can use it to specify the value:

```
UPDATE votes v
   INNER JOIN topics t ON v.topic_id = t.topic_id
SET v.yesno = 1,
   t.num_yes = IF(v.yesno = 1, t.num_yes + 1, t.num_yes),
   t.num_no = IF(v.yesno = 1, t.num_no, t.num_no + 1)
WHERE v.user_id = ? 
   AND v.topic_id = ?
```

And here is some sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9488b/1).

Good luck.

Comment: +1. Or, it might be clearer to specify e.g. `t.num_yes=t.num_yes+IF(v.yesno=1,1,0)` and `t.num_no=t.num_no+IF(v.yesno=1,0,1)`. It's the same result, but I think it makes it more clear (at least when I read the expression, that we are (conditionally) adding 1 to the current value.

Answer (score 0):

I have a two-part answer:

First, you can't do what you want, which is to choose which column is updated based on a row's value. The `UPDATE` statement has very specific syntax.

Second, you can get the result you wanted anyway:

```
UPDATE
    votes,
    topics
SET votes.yesno = 1,
    topics.num_yes = topics.num_yes + (0 XOR votes.yesno),
    topics.num_no  = topics.num_no  + (1 XOR votes.yesno)
WHERE topics.id = votes.topic_id
```

You could use `IF` in the `SET` part too, but I think my expression emphasizes that you're updating only one of the columns.